# What's the font name from image

Tags: web, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I need to know the name of the font used in the [freelancer.com](http://freelancer.com) logo? I tried to find out using **[WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)** but without success.

I really need this font name.
Thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) has a [forum](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/) where you can post a graphic containing the font in question and (with luck) get responses from actual people who may be able to identify it.